# css transform matrix image not retaining same position

Tags: javascript, css, math, matrix, transform

Please excuse me if I am not making it clear, however I will try my level best to get things clear

I am trying to flip the image, since it is web application I choose css transform matrix to perform this flipping and tried the following snippet and it does the work but have issue in positioning

```
svgCanvas.changeSelectedAttribute("transform","matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)");   // Consider svgCanvas as element
```

**Before Flip**

[image]

**After Flip**

[image]

Doing so is not retaining the same position as you see in the image. Am I doing it right?

**Updated Question**

In the first flip it work as you suggested but it differs from the next flips. I have applied same `MX = Left + Width/2` for all flips.

**After First Flip**

[image]

**After Second Flip**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your transformation matrix is for mirroring about vertical line X = 0, so coordinates become negative.

I think you need to mirror image about middle line `MX = Left + Width/2`, so your matrix should look like `matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 2 * MX, 0)`

Comment: May I know what Left means?

Comment: Left is initial position of image left edge at canvas (may be zero). And `Width` is image width

Comment: It works on the first flip and again when I try to flip unable to retain the position it goes somewhere else

Comment: Do you apply this (the same) matrix several times or do something else?

Comment: Please see my **Updated Question**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122901/discussion-between-overflow-and-mbo).